# Region of interest or mask as input to CNN, for faster feedforward computation

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

My input image is huge and only a small irregularly shaped region shall be used as input. I cannot crop it because the shape of the ROI causes the cropped region to be almost the same dimension as the input. I understand the receptive field and background context stuff, which impacts accuracy. Still, i am curious if any framework allows me to specify a binary mask as ROI?